# VSCode or Delve issue - Unable to test at all

Tags: testing, go, visual-studio-code, code-coverage, delve

I have two projects on GitHub (https://github.com/NlaakStudios) (gowaf and ezgo). Debugging and Testing with VSCode and Delve work perfectly with the gowaf repo using the default launch.json. It does not work with ezgo which is just the config from gowaf moved into a different repo.
With gowaf I get the "Run Packed test" and "Run file Test" options above the package and test functions. With ezgo I do not. gowaf was created and was being debugged and tested pre-last VSCode update and ezgo after update.
Both are frameworks with no main package, so I need test enabled for non-main binaries (as I have been doing). Below is the output from the config package in gowaf (working) and ezgo (not working)

*gowaf/config/*

> Running tool: D:\Go\bin\go.exe test
>   -coverprofile=C:\Users\Nlaak\AppData\Local\Temp\go-code-cover -timeout 30s
>
> PASS coverage: 91.8% of statements ok 
>     */d*/GO_Projects/src/github.com/NlaakStudios/gowaf/config   0.059s
>   Success: Tests passed.

*ezgo/config/*

> API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:27828 not an executable file could
>   not remove
>   d:\GO_Projects\src\github.com\NlaakStudios\ezgo\config\debug.test:
>   remove
>   d:\GO_Projects\src\github.com\NlaakStudios\ezgo\config\debug.test: The
>   system cannot find the file specified. Process exiting with code: 1

My current focus is on code coverage and this is just killing me. Complete stop and I cannot figure it out for the life of me. Any help would be appreciated. I have TeamViewer if you want to actually get your hands dirty with it as i monitor.
Thanks in advance...

```
Environment Information & Versions
------------------------------------------------------------
Windows 10 Home (all updates)
------------------------------------------------------------
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.0.0
Build: $Id: c98a142125d0b17bb11ec0513bde346229b5f533 $
------------------------------------------------------------
go version go1.10.3 windows/amd64
------------------------------------------------------------
VSCode Version Info
Version: 1.25.0
Commit: 0f080e5267e829de46638128001aeb7ca2d6d50e
Date: 2018-07-05T13:11:58.697Z
Electron: 1.7.12
Chrome: 58.0.3029.110
Node.js: 7.9.0
V8: 5.8.283.38
Architecture: x64
```